# raphael change animation direction

Tags: svg, raphael

simple by using rapheal i successfully make animation along path , but i can't reverse the animation direction ,,, just how to make it animate to the other direction when clicking the same path .

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0,1024,768);

var pathOne   = paper.path(['M', 15,15 , 100,75]).attr({'stroke-width':18}).data("id",1);

//and this is just the circle
var circle = paper.circle(0, 0, 13).attr({
        fill: '#09c', cursor: 'pointer'
});

//make the path as custom attribute so it can ba accessed
function pathPicker(thatPath){
    paper.customAttributes.pathFactor = function(distance) {
            var point = thatPath.getPointAtLength(distance *     thatPath.getTotalLength());
            var dx = point.x,
                dy = point.y;
                return {
                    transform: ['t', dx, dy]
                };
            }
    }

    //initialize for first move
    pathPicker(pathOne);
    circle.attr({pathFactor: 0}); // Reset

    //Asign first path and first move
    function firstMove(){
        circle.animate({pathFactor: 1}, 1000});
    }

    pathOne.click(function(){
        firstMove();
    });
```

Comment: Can you get it working on a jsfiddle, as it is, it doesn't run.

Comment: i updated the code it should work now . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the original to run, so here is something using the main bits that should suit...

There's not a lot to it, get the length of the path, iterate over the length, draw object at the path. It uses the Raphael customAttributes to be able to animate it. I've added a custom toggle to make it easy to switch between them.

These are the key changes..

```
var len = pathOne.getTotalLength();

paper.customAttributes.along = function (v) {
    var point = pathOne.getPointAtLength(v * len);
    return {
             transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
            };
};

circle.attr({ along: 0 });

function animateThere( val ) {
    val = +!val; // toggle
    pathOne.click( function() { animateThere( val ) } );
    circle.animate({ along: val }, 2000 ); 
};


pathOne.click( function() { animateThere(0) } );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfaspz0u/13/)

For completeness, you may want to do some extra checks like only allow the click if the animation has finished or something, as there may be a problem if you quickly click a lot and it buffering up animations.

Comment: yeb it does work and it was very simple too ... thanks alot